# SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail cbSize

Tags: c#, windows

I am attempting to adapt some existing C# USB control code to work in a 64bit application.

I have been having issues with the [SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetaila) method in regards to the `cbSize` value of the [SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/ns-setupapi-sp_device_interface_detail_data_a) structure.

The documentation for SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail says:

> The cbSize member always contains the size of the fixed part of the
> data structure, not a size reflecting the variable-length string at
> the end.

The existing 32 bit code used a fixed `cbSize` value of 6 (with no explanation as to why). Through trial and error I have determined that the  value must 8 for 64bit execution, but don't understand why.

Assuming the DWORD value for cbSize is fixed 4 bytes (which would match other methods I've fixed), that would mean the char array length is either 2 or 4 depending on the bit count. Neither of those are the length of pointers for their respective bit count so where do these numbers come from?

Comment: It is actually the 32-bit declaration that is goofy.  Packing uses two basic rules, a field of the struct must be aligned if its size is equal or less to the packing limit in effect (Pack property in the C# declaration).  Adding extra non-used bytes before the field if necessary.   And the field must still be aligned correctly if the struct is used in an array.  Padding with extra non-used bytes added to the end of the struct if necessary.  The goofy part is that the 32-bit SDK defined Pack=1 for the setupapi structs, very unusual.  That got fixed in the 64-bit SDK, Pack=8 as normal.

Comment: ANYSIZE_ARRAY = 1, so the "fixed" part is 4 bytes for the DWORD and 2 bytes for a single CHAR.  Since Pack=1, no padding is added and the size is 4+2=6.  In 64-bit code it is still 4+2, but with Pack=8 it must pad with 2 bytes to ensure the DWORD is aligned when used in an array.

Comment: @HansPassant Wow that is extremely obtuse. Is there somewhere the differing packing size is documented or was my only hope of understanding that someone who already knew came to help?

Comment: Everybody can see it, nobody understands it.  [Line #83 in the setupapi.h SDK file](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/9b69fd26ac0c7d0b83d378dba01080e93349c2ed/Include/10.0.16299.0/um/SetupAPI.h#L83).

Comment: @HansPassant If being in the code qualified as being documented I think a lot of programmers would be ecstatic with their suddenly reduced workload, but fair enough  to MS that it was visible some way. Thank you!